# Android studio 3.0 showing following error while creating new project

Tags: android, gradle, project

I recently updated my android studio to 3.0 and after updating i just created new project in android studio 3.0 after downloading some files it's showing the error as shown below:

[image]

Comment: You forgot to post the error.

Comment: add the error please

Answer (score 0):

"Just remove .gradle folder, reopen project and rebuild. It helped me.": [The System cannont find the file specified Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145014/the-system-cannont-find-the-file-specified-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Go to gradle -> gradle-wrapper.properties
put this line
**distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip**