# android studio cannot find the file

Tags: android-studio

my android studio says gradle build finished but does not run tasks because and gives the error
 C:\Users\The Lepdungs\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2.gradle\buildOutputCleanup\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: I think the same issue was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40145014/5335885) so, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try going to *Build* -> *Clean Project*.

If that doesn't work then try *File* -> *Invalidate Caches/Restart*.

The problem is due to caches that android studio has made, so when it creates new files, there's a problem. One of the above steps should solve it.